# How to remove line break after DIV in CSS

Tags: css

Is there a way to prevent a line break after a div with css, but to have one div min width and the other max width?

For example I have

```
<div class="label">My Label:</div>
<div class="text">My text</div>
```

and want it to display like:

```
My Label: My text
```

Where My text floats right, and my label takes all the remaining width?

I am using the following CSS, but the .text div keeps wrapping:

```
div
{
    display: inline-block;
}

.label {
    border:1px solid blue;
    width:100%;
}

.text {
    border:1px solid red;
float:right;
}
```

***UPDATE: JS FIDDLE ** http://jsfiddle.net/jPrMG/

Thanks for your help

Comment: You would need to change them from being `block` elements to `inline-block` elements like so http://jsfiddle.net/E537f/

Comment: How can I set the .label div to take all the screen width whilst the .text div is pushed right?

Comment: Like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/E537f/3/

Comment: Yes, but the .label needs to take all the remaining width; this solution doesn't do that. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/d5Q4W/ the divs are wrapping. I want the .text div on the same line

Comment: That's not the code I gave you.  My code has it on the same line no?  http://jsfiddle.net/E537f/3/

Comment: Change the tag from `<div>` to `<span>` should solve the problem.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's not a 'line break' that you're seeing; it's because `<div>` elements default to being a `block` element.

If you want to change the behaviour so that they appear on the same line, you can change the `display` property in CSS, like so:

```
display:inline;
```

or

```
display:inline-block;
```

If you still want to have `width` or `min-width` property (as stated in the question) then you would need the latter of those two, `inline-block`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It does, but it doesn't solve the wrapping issue I'm facing. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/jPrMG/

Comment: @alias51 - in the fiddle, just remove the `width:100%` from the label. As things stand, it extends the label the full width across the screen, so of course the next element moves down onto the next line.

Comment: or you could just use `float:left` and `float:right` for the label and the field.

Answer (score 14):

You can use CSS table model:

```
.label {
    border:1px solid blue;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}

.text {
    border:1px solid red;
    display: table-cell;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jPrMG/3/)